# Node.JS rename file in mounted drive

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to be able to rename files using Node.JS and then rename them back via a separate system and then rename them again via Node.JS.

When renaming a file using Node.JS fs.rename it works the first time, but when trying renaming it back to the original name and then running Node.JS fs.rename to rename it again it does not work, there's no error or anything. i.e.

```
await fs.promises.rename('/var/lib/sitecontents/old.csv', '/var/lib/sitecontents/new.csv') # Works
# Rename back to old.csv using Window file browser connected to the share
await fs.promises.rename('/var/lib/sitecontents/old.csv', '/var/lib/sitecontents/new.csv') # Doesn't work, no error
```

I tried using the fs-extras library and the move function and it returned this error: "Error: Source and destination must not be the same.", even thought the files had different names.

I have also tried to copy and delete

```
const rename = async (path) => {
  const newPath = `${path}_processed`;
  try {
    await fs.promises.copyFile(path, newPath, async (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      await fs.promises.unlink(path, (ierr) => {
        if (ierr) throw ierr;
        console.log(`-----removed: ${path}`);
      });
      console.log(`-----moved: ${path}, ${newPath}`);
    });
  } catch (t) {
    console.log(t);
  }
}
```

Which gives me this message:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unknown system error -116

I have also tried child_process.exec with no luck

```
exec(`mv ${path} ${newPath}`);
```

Error I am getting from that is

> {
> killed: false,
> code: 1,
> signal: null,
> cmd: 'mv /var/lib/sitedata/azure_devops_integration/dev/twoo.csv /var/lib/sitedata/azure_devops_integration/dev/twoo.csv.error',
> stdout: '',
> stderr: 'mv: ‘/var/lib/sitedata/azure_devops_integration/dev/twoo.csv’ and ‘/var/lib/sitedata/azure_devops_integration/dev/twoo.csv.error’ are the same file\n'
> }

I'm using Node.JS 12.19.0 on RHEL. The folder that the files are in is mounted via a shared drive, and there is only issues when renaming the files back to the original name via windows share. If I rename the files using RHEL and the mv command there is no issue.

Comment: When you want to rename your file back, you probably need to switch parameters?

Comment: And in your second approach with copy and delete, you have an improper usage of `fs.promises.copyFile` You passed a callback function, but you have to use `then()` or `await` as it is a promise ...

Comment: Updated the second approach. When renaming the file back I have been doing it via the windows file explorer

Comment: So I'm thinking its to do with the way that I'm mounting the cifs drive to the system and some sort of caching. I added an exec call to `ls /path/to/directory` before the copy file and it seems to run as expected. Now to figure out how to mount the drive correctly, currently using these options `_netdev,noperm,username=user,password=pass,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=3.0`